# How calculate average time in Excel (if sum of hours more, than 24)

Tags: excel, time

I have some time values like 10:00, 8:50, 9:45 and so on (24 hours format).
I want to know how I can compute average value of this 3 items, if sum of hours more than 24 (if less, then no problems)?

Thanks.

Thanks for everyone. It works, if just type values in cells and try to find average, but it work weird if I use time, which already result of my calculation already. Here screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Non-programming. Better asked at Super User

Comment: How are you calculating the values in C6:K6 - is there a formula in there? Those values must actually be over 24 hours (try custom formatting as [h]:mm to see actual values). Result in H7 is probably `28:28:53` - format that cell as [h]:mm to see that too. Quick fix is to average the time only using this formula `=SUMPRODUCT(MOD(C6:K6,1))/COUNT(C6:K6)` but I recommend you fix the values

Comment: I still don't entirely understand how this formula work, but all calculations correct now. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

As you would any other numeric values (e.g. using the AVERAGE() function).

Use a formatting mask of:

```
[hh]:mm
```

if you want to display more than 24 hours (e.g. for the SUM() function).

Answer (score 1):

Calculating the average of a set of times or list of wind directions could be regarded as similar to computing the average of a set of vectors (values containing both direction and magnitude). It is therefore necessary to equate the time values to their respective positions on a unity circle, derive their perpendicular component values and sum these as is the case for taking the "average" of any such form of cyclic group.

Say you have two times, 23:00 and 01:00, then a normal average calculation (sumproduct/count) will leave you with the incorrect value of 12:00 [(23+1)/2] instead of the correct 24:00 / 00:00 value. If you however regard 23:00 as equal to the vector 1<345° on a twenty-four hour circle and 01:00 equal to 1<15° you can obtain their vector average [cos(345°)+cos(15°) + i*(sin(345°)+sin(15°))] = 1<360° a value equating back to 00:00 on the 24 hour circle.
Note however that this method will cancel out times exactly 12 hours apart, e.g. if you only have 01:00 and 13:00 it is not possible to determine an average time.

I'll just leave you with the formulas then (times in A column)

```
TIME_TO_DEGREES                     COSINE              SINE
=(360/24)*(HOUR(A2)+MINUTE(A2)/60)  =COS(RADIANS(B2))   =SIN(RADIANS(B2))
=(360/24)*(HOUR(A3)+MINUTE(A3)/60)  =COS(RADIANS(B3))   =SIN(RADIANS(B3))
=(360/24)*(HOUR(A4)+MINUTE(A4)/60)  =COS(RADIANS(B4))   =SIN(RADIANS(B4))
=(360/24)*(HOUR(A5)+MINUTE(A5)/60)  =COS(RADIANS(B5))   =SIN(RADIANS(B5))

                                    [C8]                [D8]
               COMPONENT AVERAGES   =AVERAGE(C2:C7)     =AVERAGE(D2:D7)

AVERAGE DEGREES                     DEGREES_TO_HOUR     MAGNITUDE
=ROUND(DEGREES(IF(C8=0,ACOS(C8),
IF(D8=0,ASIN(D8),
ATAN(D8/C8)))),3)
+IF(C8<0,180,0)
+IF(AND(D8<0,C8=0),180,0)
+IF(AND(D8<0,C8>0),360,0)           =E8/360             =(C8^2+D8^2)^0.5
```

In the case that the magnitude is zero it is an unfeasible operation to try and compute an average time.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the `AVERAGE` function?

I tested it in excel with your values and it gives me the correct average time.

Answer (score 0):

One method is converting every cell time into **seconds** , then average these seconds and at last convert to **hh:mm:ss**  format

Answer (score 0):

Simple Just click on Cell(Time) and Converted(Automatic) into 12 hr time

i.e. if you have **00:31:24** then convert it into Full date like this **12:31:24 AM**.

After that you can use Average.